# What were those small light up oval emblems called on late 70s early 80s called?

Tags: lights, vintage

I can remember my parents having these little oval lights with the Oldsmobile emblem printed on them installed on the C pillar (on the vinyl top no less) of our 1977 Oldsmobile Cutlass.  I can remember the lights had an odd name, but I have no idea what they were called back then and its driving me nuts.

Additionally, this wasn't limited to oldsmobiles. It was a trend to have these little oval or rectangular lights on the side of the car.

Comment: I believe the lights you describe were added to these vehicles as side markers so would assume that is the legislation under which they would fall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recall calling them *opera lights*.  Maybe carriage lights as well.

[image]

There were also opera windows.

Comment: Well remembered.  Carriage lights, as a carry-over from the days of horse drawn carriages.

Comment: Good memory.  I honestly don't remember calling them this, but I was probably 10 years old at the time my parents were talking about them.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=NLOSBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=opera+lights+car&source=bl&ots=C2JIZvT_Gb&sig=NZ0NVwfuI3lSs1Gq0A2xE8Z5UC8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjr2pXe-_7dAhUpyoMKHYUtD8EQ6AEwGnoECFkQAQ#v=onepage&q=opera%20lights%20car&f=false